# Rails 3 - how to add to autocomplete another condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I use the gem [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) for the autocomplete searching of items in my database. The autocomplete is working fine, but I would need to add another condition to the generated query.

If I start to write a searched string, then is generated following query:

```
SELECT persons.id, persons.name FROM "persons" WHERE (LOWER(persons.name) ILIKE 'jo%') ORDER BY persons.name ASC LIMIT 10
```

This returns me all rows, where the name starts at `jo`.

But how could I search all persons, which name starts at `jo` and simultaneously, for example, the column `active_person`=`1`?
Is there any helper for this purpose or something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the context correctly, then **active_person** is a boolean that indicates whether the user is active or not.

If this behavior is desirable most of time - that you search for users/people that are only active then you could include a default_scope in your Person model like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:active_person => 1)
end
```

This way any query that is ever generated will be also checking that active_person = 1

More on default scopes here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: Thanks, this solution is working, but just particularly. This line of code add to every query `where(:active_person => 1)`. I would need to add this line just to some of queries...

Comment: In which cases would you like that line to be applied? If you can identify specific cases, we can add a condition to when that line is applied. Specific controller actions?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that @Andrei 's answer is correct, but its not what I was looking for. I guess its same for @user984621 too. What I was looking for is I want to add an extra condition to the query.
By reading this https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/orm/active_record.rb

I found that rails autocomplete supports additional conditions, you just have to pass another parameter to the default usage, like this

```
autocomplete :user, :name, :where => { :role => 'employee'}
```

instead of this

```
autocomplete :user, :name
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `WHERE (LOWER(persons.name) ILIKE 'jo%')` to `WHERE (LOWER(persons.name) ILIKE 'jo%') AND active_person = 1`

You can chain together loads of clauses with `AND`s and `OR` in that way.

Note that this is really a question about SQL: your title and tags are a bit misleading.

Comment: The changes you have suggested are pretty clear, but the point is - how to update the query, which is generated with the gem.